# Entered Values in next Activity and Back

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app which consists of 7 pages and the user can go through these 7 pages with  a button. He can go back to the previous page with the own button of the mobile device. As said, if I click the button the user goes to the next page. Besides, if the user clicks the "Back" button of the device it goes back to the previous activity and all the entered values remain the same. However, what I want is that if the user goes to the next activity and the user had entered before some values in that activity, these values remain there.(not empty as is happens now). I guess that this happens because everytime I click the button, a NEW activity is launched.

Is there a method to achieve this without using SharedPreferences, XML, etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the back is pressed then by default the activity is destroyed. the only way to save its data is to store it somewhere just like `SharedPreferences` to avoid this activity destruction you can set it as `single instance` in `menifest` then on back press call this method `moveTaskToBack(true);` Now whenever you launch the activity again it will not recreate itself . also remove the super.onBackPressed(); method from that method. (`onBackPressed()`)

in manifest do like this

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
```

Comment: I've done this public void onBackPressed(){ moveTaskToBack(true);} and when clicking the Back Button it just minimizes the app. How can I do creating a single instance in the manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Before starting another activity, you can put key value pairs like hashmaps in intents and you can retrieve these values in the activity you are calling.
You can look into :-

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, SecondActivity.class);
returnIntent.putExtra("name","abc");
startActivity(returnIntent,11);
```

And in you other activity result method, you can do

```
if(requestCode == 11){
Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
String name = bundle.getString("name");
}
```

You can look into this.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by calling startActivityForResult() for starting the next Activity...when you come back to previous activity your data will remain on the screen

Comment: What i want is to maintain the data in the following activities, not the previous ones.